# How CDN knows which Edge sever should it redirect the client to?

Tags: cdn

I'm trying to learn more about how CDN works. How does it knows which Edge sever should it redirect the client to for lowest latency? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, Upstream configuration is used in Nginx webserver.
nginx redirect users's requests to the destination server.
sample of Nginx upstream is as bellow.

```
upstream example.com {
    server example.com;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;

    }
```